# How to get electron autoUpdater instance inside Angular 9 app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron

So I have an application that can run in electron, and it can auto update. The update server is up and can be used.

The problem is, my updater process runs in electron main process, not inside Angular app. I want the users to be able to check, and manually update the application themselves, which I think we need to implement main process instance inside my Angular app.

Here is how I call the updater inside main.js.

```js
if (!require('electron-is-dev')) {
    require('./updater');
} else {
    console.log('App is running in dev environment')
}
```

And here is a slice of my updater.js

```js
const { app, dialog, autoUpdater } = require('electron');

const server = 'http://my-release-server.com:5000';
const url = `${server}/update/${process.platform}/${app.getVersion()}`;

console.log(`[autoUpdater] init ${url}`);
autoUpdater.setFeedURL({ url });

setInterval(() => {
    autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
}, 30000)

autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', () => {
    console.log('[autoUpdater] Checking for updates');
});

// And other events handler.
```

My autoUpdater works like charm when I am using default setup, which runs the updater inside the main electron process, but I can not show or inform the user about the updating process.

So, is there any solution or right way to implement this thing? I learnt in some article to use electron remote which handled inter process communication, can I use that? Can I use angular service to handle these things?

Thank you.